# Looking for a book where some girls and boys have the ability to manipulate life and time like the Fates

Tags: story-identification

I have a friend that wants to read this because I read it a couple of years ago, and I can describe some of it, but I can't remember the title or the author.

There is a girl who doesn't want to be in the highest position of the "manipulators" like every other girl. When she goes into training, she figures out that the government is "ripping" out people who are not useful, and that their world is built upon the old Earth.

She is given the highest position, and is envied by all other girls. Later she escapes to the world beneath and finds out her father is one of the rare men who can manipulate the strings of life and time. She returns to the new world with the help of Einstein and kills the president.

Comment: Can you actually provide details in the question we can't read your mind. Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can add in any more details.

Comment: @Edlothiad i did. better? :)

Comment: Looks amazing now!

Comment: You read it a couple of years ago, but was it new then or could it have been old/older?

Comment: @Möoz idk I can’t remember but it was fairly new